# nested/inner scope of variables

Tags: scala, scope

What's the exact deal with scope regarding variables in Scala?

When I open curly brackets I can still access the value of the outer vars (and modify them if vars):

```
scala> var mmm = 4
mmm: Int = 4

scala> {
     | println(mmm)
     | mmm += 2
     | println(mmm)
     | }
4
6

scala> println(mmm)
6
```

But Odersky says on page 180 or his book that

> In a Scala program, an inner variable is said to shadow a like-named outer variable,
>   because the outer variable becomes invisible in the inner scope.

This seems even weirder:

```
scala> val a = 4
a: Int = 4

scala> {
     | println(a)
     | }
4
```

So do I get a copy of it created in the inner scope?

```
scala> val a = 4
a: Int = 4

scala> {
     | val a = 8
     | }
```

Why can I say val again if its immutable?

```
scala> val a = 4
a: Int = 4

scala> {
     | println(a)
     | val a = 8
     | println(a)
     | }
```

But for this one I get an error:

```
error: forward reference extends over definition of value a
              println(a)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create a new one in the block, the new one shadows the old (outer) one.  If you don't, you refer to the outer one.

It doesn't matter where in the block the new one is created; if it appears *anywhere*, it shadows the outer one.

So,

```
val a = 5
{ println(a) }  // This is outer a

val a = 5
{ val a = 8; println(a) }  // This is inner a

val a = 5
{ println(a); val a = 8 }  // This is broken
                           // you try to print the inner a
                           // but it doesn't exist yet
```

---

Edit: let's unpack the last one

```
val a = 5
// Okay, I have something called a

{  // Oh, new block beginning!  Maybe there are local variables
  println(a)
  val a = 8    // Yeah, there's one!
               // And it's got the same name as the outer one
               // Oh well, who needs the outer one anyway?
}

// Waitaminute, what was that block supposed to do?
{
  println(a)   // Inner block has an a, so this must be the inner a
  val a = 8    // Which is 8
}

// Hang on, operations happen in order
{
  println(a)   // What inner a?!

// Abort, abort, abort!!!!
```

Comment: im still confused i just cannot get my head round this (i guess its my fault):
now I know the shell is different - but i can understand how it works, say for instance:
martin@mintbox ~ $ `a=5
martin@mintbox ~ $ (echo $a ; a=8; echo $a)
5
8
martin@mintbox ~ $ echo $a
5`
there i can see a scope created (with a copy of a var and the subshell cannot affect the val of the outer - but can the inner copy
but how do you explain my first example, where the inner increment changes the outer value?

Comment: @mbrambley - The inner increment is an increment of the outer value.  You don't throw away all your variables just because you open some braces.  It's like subclassing in that respect: the child still has access to everything in the parent, but can add their own stuff (or replace the parent's stuff).  It's not _actually_ subclassing, but maybe this will help you see what is going on.

Comment: @mbrambley - Also, yes, it scans for variables _before_ it executes anything.  (This is how you can refer to a `def` further down the block.)  I'm not sure exactly how many passes there are.  I notice at least three obvious ones while compiling.

Comment: thanks i think ive got it now - i think im going to avoid vars of the same name in inner scopes until i can think of a use of them.
... scared of my own shadow now

Comment: But what about vars? If I assign them, would the change be visible outside? My similar (I guess) code does not work:
    var finalWorld:WorldModel = null
    LifeActors.run(world, new WorldModelListener {
        override def worldUpdated(world: WorldModel) = {
        finalWorld = world
       }
    }, 3) //3 iterations
    val alive = finalWorld.getElements.filter(_.isAlive). Damnit, dont know how to paste code in here, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Blocks don't change the visibility of outer variables per se. Only if you declare variables with the same name within the inner scope, as the Odersky quote explains.

Your first two examples don't do this, so the outer variable is plainly visible within the inner scope, and Odersky's quote doesn't apply. The `a` in the inner scope is the same as the `a` in the outer scope, there is no copying involved.

In the third example however, the two `a`s are two independent `val` variables, i.e. the inner `a` is not *redefining* the outer `a`, just *shadowing* it as per Odersky's quote, e.g.:

```
val a = 4
println(a)  // prints 4 - outer a
{
  val a = 8;
  println(a)  // prints 8 - inner a
}
println(a)  // prints 4 - outer a in scope again
```

I.e. after exiting the inner block, you see that the outer `a` with its original value is still there.

However, the code you show in the third example is highly ambiguous, as it is hard to decide without deeper knowledge of the language specification, which variable your first `println(a)` statement refers to. I don't have an exact reference at hand but I believe such code is disallowed by the compiler as this style provides no benefit while it is inherently error prone.